# ApplicationBarIconButton event not firing after chooser task

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a global app bar in my App.xaml.  One of the buttons calls the PhoneNumberChooserTask-

```
    private void AppBarContacts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneNumberChooserTask chooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
        chooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(chooserTask_Completed);
        chooserTask.Show(); 
    }
```

and the result is passed on

```
    void chooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
    {
        string phoneNumber = "";

        if ((TaskResult.Cancel != e.TaskResult) && (TaskResult.None == e.TaskResult))
        {
            phoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber;
        }

        PhoneApplicationFrame root = (PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual;
        root.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?number=" + phoneNumber, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

After that navigation, though, the ApplicationBarIconButton's click event no longer fires. [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/e079d99e-d2ac-47ab-a87e-f4ce0d3660d5) suggests it's a known issue but the work around they suggest I can't use because I can't access the NavigationService from App.xaml.cs.

I can get around that by having a page that does nothing but launch the task (I tried adding a flag like  "/MainPage.xaml?getnumber=1" and doing it there but that gets called again when the chooser returns, so it just loops forever) but that means you get a blank page before the chooser launches, which doesn't look very good.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you try to put `Navigate` method inside `Dispatcher` block?

Comment: @Ku6opr Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => root.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?number=" + phoneNumber, UriKind.Relative))); gets an "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Action)'" error.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Ku6opr Although Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => root.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?number=" + strNumber, UriKind.Relative))); does seem to work.

Comment: Ben, just compile or solve your problem?

Comment: @Ku6opr Sorry for the delay! I think that has solved my problem, yes, thank you.  If you leave your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows Phone 8.1. My appbar is on mainpage. But the tapped event just won't fire. However, another button does fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `NavigationService.Navigated` event subscription, i.e. `PhoToChooserTask.Completed` event is raised before `OnNavigatedTo` so, if you call `root.Navigate` from it, this strange behavior appears.

The workaround for this is to call `root.Navigate` in first frame draw (after `OnNavigatedTo` and so on). `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` can be used for this, so the full code is:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    root.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?number=" + strNumber, UriKind.Relative));
});
```